# How to remove an arry from a list of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I created a list using the following NumPy arrays

```
a=np.arange(1,10,1)
b=np.arange(10,19,1)
c=np.arange(19,28,1)

#a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#b = [10,11,12,13, 14,15,16, 17,18]

#c =[19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]

list_array = [a,b,c]
```

However when I try to remove any array from the list using list_array.remove  I get the following error

```
list_array.remove(b)
>>ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**My question is how do I remove an array from a list of numpy arrays?**

Comment: Please properly show your code used to generate the arrays. What you have written there are lists.

Comment: This one's working for me. Which version of python are you using?. If you need a fix for that try `list_array = [lis for lis in list_array if lis !=b]`

Answer (score 3):

Python does not have a "where" keyword. You have to declare your arrays first and then declare the array of arrays, then you will be able to remove without any trouble.

For your information, there are no Arrays in Python, only lists in the which you can put whatever types you desire. Writing `a = ["hello", 2, 6.48]` is perfectly valid.

```
a= [1,2,3,
    4,5,6,
    7,8,9]

b = [10,11,12,
     13, 14,15,
     16, 17,18]

c =[19,20,21,
    22,23,24,
    25,26,27]


list_array = [a, b, c]

list_array.remove(b)

print(list_array) #Prints [a, c]
```

Comment: You must be right, as it wasn't commented out I supposed it was.

Comment: This only works because you are using **lists** here for `a`, `b` and `c`, because the OP was lazy in how the numpy arrays were shown in the question. But the whole point of the problem here is that numpy arrays do not support equality comparisons in the way that lists do, hence the error message shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.array_equiv` to test whether two numpy arrays are equal.

You will have combine it with your own loop to implement the equivalent of `remove`, for example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = a+9
c = b+9

list_array = [a,b,c]

for i in range(len(list_array) - 1, -1, -1):
    if np.array_equiv(list_array[i], a):
        list_array.pop(i)

print(list_array)
```

If preferred, you can write the `for` statement as:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(list_array))):
```

but the important thing is that it loops through the indices *backwards*.